# Count statement in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have 3 tables (user, questions, answers) in the question table i have id_question and question, in the answer table I have `id_question`, `user_id` and answer. I want to run a query that gives me the number of answer's per question.

I want a column that has all questions that were answered (not the `id_question`) and 3 other columns (yes, no, maybe) that have the number of times that that answer was given to a question. The question column can't have repeated questions  (even though users can answer the same questions and give different answers, I want the number of yes, nos and maybes to each question). I'm only created the yes column, having trouble in creating the other 2

Here's what I did so far:

```
SELECT 
    questions.question, COUNT(answers.answer) As Yes
FROM 
    answers 
INNER JOIN 
    questions ON questions.id_question = answers.id_question 
WHERE 
    answer = 'yes' 
GROUP BY 
    question  
ORDER BY 
    questions.id_question  ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT questions.question,
    SUM(IF(answer='yes', 1, 0)) AS Yes,
    SUM(IF(answer='no', 1, 0)) AS No,
    SUM(IF(answer='maybe', 1, 0)) AS Maybe
FROM answers 
INNER JOIN questions ON questions.id_question=answers.id_question 
GROUP BY question
ORDER BY questions.id_question ASC
```

Comment: Wow!!! It worked. Can you explain to me the how the line's that have SUM IF work?

Comment: Sure, `IF` statement will return "1" when condition `answer='yes'` is true and "0" when it false. Then we `SUM` up this results of `IF` statements and it become  basic math: `1 + 0 + 1 + 1`. For better understanding try to run the same query without `GROUP BY` and `SUM` functions and you will see what your data look like before aggregation.